# Code for Duplication Prevention in a customized requirement

Tags: apex, trigger

I have object 'Account' which has Name, ID_proof__c and ID_number_*c fields. There are almost 62,000 records which have close to 8000 duplicates. I have two more fields, key1*_c and key2__c, where key1= (Text)ID_proof + ID_number , and key2= Name + key1.

I need a trigger for the following :

Problem statement - Any new record having duplicate key2_*c should be able to save.
But any record having duplicate key1*_c value but not key2__c should throw an duplication error. Also only addition of new records should only have any effect, when there is any match with any of the 62000 records, existing records with duplicates in themselves should be as-is.

The solution using a workflow only works on new records created, so that is not an option as I need to work on previous data.

Insight : Whenever someone saves data, the ID Proof type and ID Number gets recorded. For any account, a person should only be able to save data (even if it is a duplicate) when his Name matches with his ID proof and ID number. Conversely, if the ID type and ID number from older record matches, but not the Name, that should throw an error.

What changes can I do to this sample code for this to work (code used in prev req.) :

```
//Loop to retrieve all Key__c values
Set <String> smyKeys = new Set<String>();
for (Account nAcc:Trigger.new)
{
    smyKeys.add(nAcc.myKey__c);
}



List <Account> lAccounts = [SELECT Id, myKey__c FROM Account where myKey__c in :smyKeys];

//Creating a Map <myKey__c -> Account> You can use just a set of MyKey__c if you only want to detect duplicates. With the Map you can also add a more descriptive message
Map <String,Account> mKeyToAccountId = new Map<String,Account>(); 

for (Account a:lAccounts)
{
    mKeyToAccountId.put(a.myKey__c,a);
}

//Loop again through your Updated/Inserted accounts
for (Account aNew:Trigger.New)
{
    if (mKeyToAccountId.containsKey(aNew.myKey__c))
    {

        aNew.addError('whatever message...'); 
    } 
}
```

etc etc.

Comment: Have you already tried writing such trigger ? If you're expecting someone to just write one based on your requirements your question is going to be closed

Comment: yes, I have written a trigger , just want to know a procedure where it can overlook one criteria and catch an error in another. Also I have tried using a workflow, which didn't produce the desired results.